# What's the proper way to present an alert view like Xcode's build success alert on macOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have been experimenting ways to show an alert view like that seen in Xcode (when build succeeded). I'm entirely new to Cocoa and have managed to get a NSWindow to show up using the following

```
    let alert = AlertView()

    // Create the window and set the content view.
    let window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220.0, height: 220.0),
        styleMask: [.closable, .titled, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.titleVisibility = .hidden
    window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
    window.contentView?.wantsLayer = true
    window.center()
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: alert)
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    window.isOpaque = false
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

After the thing presents itself, I used DispatchQueue to wait for a couple second then call window.close() to close the window. But I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Here's a screenshot of the alert view I'm trying to present. [image: Xcode build alert view]

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks a lot!